# Oracle grant privileges to a group of users and a certain data

Tags: oracle, privileges, sql-grant

I have my database on Oracle and I want to grant privileges to a certain group of users (for example, considering they're identfied by an id, users 1 to 9) and I also want to grant them access to a certain data (for example, a data which has a certain attribute).

Do I need to create a role in order for the group of users? And what do I have to do for only granting privileges to a certain data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't **have to** create a role (as you can grant privileges directly to those users), but - role makes it simpler to maintain. So yes, I'd suggest you to create a role, grant privileges to that role, and then grant role to any user you want.

As of *certain data*: a simple option - if you think it is an option in your case - is to create a **view** whose `WHERE` clause restricts data only to specific set of rows. Then grant access on such a view to previously mentioned role (and users will "inherit" that privilege through it).

Comment: Oh thanks, yes creating a view is great option, didnt think of it. Last question, is there a way to add a group of users to a role or do I have to add them 1 by 1?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can tell, it is "one by one".

Comment: "is there a way to add a group of users to a role or do I have to add them 1 by 1".  Just to expand on @Littlefoot - you don't 'add users to a role'.  That makes no sense, because users are not a property of a role.  You may think "it's just semantics", but words have meaning.  And 'adding a user to a role' has no meaning.  The only thing you can do with a role is grant privileges and roles to it (just like you would grant to a user), and grant the role to a user or another role.